# AirDrop on my iPhone no longer recognizes MacBook Pro, but MacBook Pro recognizes the iPhone

Tags: iphone, airdrop

Since I updated to iOS 16.7.1 on my iPhone, AirDrop can't find my MacBook Pro running 11.7.10; yet I am able to AirDrop from computer to iPhone?

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. On the MacBook, Bluetooth is turned on, and the window shows "Now discoverable as MacBook Pro", and in the Devices area it shows "Mark Porto's iPhone XR" as "Connected". Also, in the MacBook's Air Drop Window my setting reads as "...Everyone".

Comment: So the Mac is ready to talk, how about the iPhone, Those two need to pair by showing you the pairing number to enter